# Ruby on rails facebook like notification without page refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am into a process of developing the facebook or stackoverflow like notification in my rails app. when the new activity gets stored in the database i get the new notification flashed on the browser. without refreshing the page. there is a way by giving ajax request with the setInterval . but that looks so dull as there will be many requests on the server , i just want to flash notification on the homepage only when it gets stored in the database

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no "take this code and be happy" solution for your problem, since what you are asking for are websockets and rails 4 doesn't support them out of the box (rails 5 does with the new "action_cable").

You might want to have a look at these links:

[pusher web sockets](https://pusher.com/websockets)

[websockets rails gem](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails)

[pusher gem tutorial](http://blog.kiskolabs.com/post/1014820673/realtime-client-push-to-rails-application-with)

Comment: Obviously i dont want pre-made codes. and Unfortunately i use Rails 4 and the application is existing so cant change the framework version :( . Is there any way for the Rails 4 ?

Comment: Well yes, of course :) It's just that it's too big of a topic to cover it here. I used to go with the pusher gem for rails, but the websockets-rails gem I posted might work for you, idk (I added a pusher gem tutorial to the links). If you have never done it, you have some reading to do ;)

Comment: It also depends on what server your app is running on, what platform you are hosting it and stuff like that :-/

Comment: @Ninigi, why can't you upgrade to Rails 5? Of course it's a big task but it would ease a lot of future tasks - like the websockets

Comment: Ill surely look into it .. thanks for the tutorial btw :)

Comment: @TheChamp I guess your question was supposed to be for user4965201 ^^ Depending on how big the app he is doing this for is, it might just not be worth it?

Comment: yeah true :) typo there haha